# Recursive programming with Stack in ASM and LC3

Tags: recursion, assembly, stack, multiplication, lc3

So I'm new to assembly and I'm also not pretty good at recursion, this is the code that I have so far and it is supposed to translate from :

```
int mult(int n, int m) {
 if (n == 1)
 return m;
 else if (m == 1)
 return n;
 else
 return mult(n-1,m-1)+n+m-1;
}
```

but for some reason I am in an infinite loop, I am also suppose to store the result in the variable PRODUCT but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do that, I've attempted in the commented code but I and I know that I need help translating the base cases and figuring out if they are returning the correct thing/value.

```
    ; main - going to calculate the product of two nonnegative numbers.
    PRODUCT .Fill 0

; input in R0 and R1
; output in R0

MULT

    ADD R6 R6 -1    ; Pushed it (closer to zero)
    STR R1 R6 0     ; storing register on stack
    ADD R6 R6 -1
    STR R2 R6 0
    ADD R6 R6 -1
    STR R3 R6 0
    ADD R6 R6 -1
    STR R4 R6 0
    ADD R6 R6 -1
    STR R5 R6 0
    ADD R6 R6 -1
    STR R7 R6 0

    ADD R2 R0 -1    ; Saves the subtraction of n from R0 to R2 
    BRz BASECASE1   ; if (n == 1) return m

    ADD R3 R1 -1    ; Saves the subtraction of m from R1 to R3
    BRz BASECASE2   ; else if (m == 1) OR if (m - 1) == 0 return n

    ; recursive case begins

    ADD R2 R0 0     ; copy n into R2
    ADD R3 R1 0 ; copy m into R3
    ADD R0 R0 -1    ; mult (n-1,
    ADD R1 R1 -1    ;   m-1)
    ADD R4 R2 R3    ; storing n+m in R4
    ADD R4 R4 -1    ; subtracting 1 form n + m and storing in R4 

    JSR MULT    ; else return mult(n-1, m-1) + n+m-1;

    ADD R5 R4 R1
    ADD R0 R5 R0
    ;ST R0, PRODUCT

BASECASE1 

    LDR R7 R6 0      ; Restoring registers
    ADD R6 R6 1
    LDR R5 R6 0
    ADD R6 R6 1
    LDR R4 R6 0
    ADD R6 R6 1
    LDR R3 R6 0
    ADD R6 R6 1
    LDR R2 R6 0
    ADD R6 R6 1
    LDR R1 R6 0
    ADD R6 R6 1
    RET     ; returns m 

BASECASE2
    LDR R7 R6 0
    ADD R6 R6 1
    LDR R5 R6 0
    ADD R6 R6 1
    LDR R4 R6 0
    ADD R6 R6 1
    LDR R3 R6 0
    ADD R6 R6 1
    LDR R2 R6 0
    ADD R6 R6 1
    LDR R1 R6 0
    ADD R6 R6 1
    RET ; returns n

.END
```

Comment: What's in my Main :                                                                 `LD R6 STACK ; Loading the address of the stack into R6 LD R0 FACT1 ; (n) Loading the variable FACT1 (3) into R0 LD R1 FACT2 ; (m) Loading the variable FACT1 (3) into R1 JSR MULT ; Calling the MULT function                        
HALT`

Answer (score 1):

You are showing a comment for the concept of main, but it does not include any code to call the function.

You need a main that loads arguments into r0 and r1 (values to be multiplied), then calls multiply with a `JSR`; after the call the main should store r0 in PRODUCT, and then use the `HALT` to stop the program.

Your variable PRODUCT should appear after your main code depending on what simulator you're using, as some simulators will execute the first thing they find (which should thus be main code).

Other comments:

- You generally have the right idea that you need to save & restore some registers, including r7 (the return address register), and that this save/restore needs to happen on the stack since this is a recursive routine.
- You are preserving n and m in r2 and r3 respectively, but don't use them later (e.g. after the call where saving them would have been important), so this is unnecessary.
- Your code after the call does a computation using R1, but that is an unknown value, since it is an argument register.
- BASECASE1 does not do what the C code says (it should return m)

Comment: I have a main I just didn't include it but my main is:  LD R6 STACK  ; Loading the address of the stack into R6

        LD R0 FACT1  ; (n) Loading the variable FACT1 (3) into R0
 LD R1 FACT2  ; (m) Loading the variable FACT1 (3) into R1
 JSR MULT  ; Calling the MULT function

        HALT

Comment: Also how would I return that value in the register do I use ADD?

Comment: Yes, you can add with zero to copy a register value from one to another.  To return m, move (using add) r1 into r0.  Btw, what simulator are you using?  I like the online one http://wchargin.github.io/lc3web/#  but it requires #'s in front of numbers.

Comment: It was downloaded from a file, it's an actual LC3 application saved to the computer, I don't really know much else. But thanks for the help on the returning registers.

Comment: I think i'm having a problem recursing with two parameters in ASM I now have :                                                                        ` ADD R3 R1 -1  ; Saves the subtraction of m from R1 to R3
 BRz BASECASE2 ; else if (m == 1) OR if (m - 1) == 0 return n

 ; recursive case begins
 
 ADD R4 R0 R1    ; storing n+m in R4
 ADD R0 R0 -1    ; mult (n-1,
 ADD R1 R1 -1 ;   m-1)
 
 ADD R4 R4 -1    ; subtracting 1 form n + m and storing in R4 
 

JSR MULT ;  else return mult(n-1, m-1) + n+m-1;
 
  ADD R5 R4 R1    ;
  ADD R0 R5 0    ; 0 was R0`

Comment: Ok, this website is not really set up for debugging: it likes Q&A, and not extended chat.  If you want you can chat me at [codementor.io](https://www.codementor.io/erikeidt), and we can have an extended conversation and look at it together.